# How to pass drawnCard into a deal function?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to pass my drawnCard, that is chosen randomly in my `drawRandomCard()` function into my `printCard()` function and `deal()` function, so it can be used in these functions. So basically how would I do this, what is the best way to pass this from one function to another, keeping the exact values, in this case a card from the deck. I'm not sure if a pointer would work. **Thanks!**

**functions.cpp**

```
void Deck::createDeck() {
deck.clear();
static const char suits[] = {'C','D','H','S'};
for (int suit=0; suit < 4; suit++)
    for (int val=1; val <=13; val++)
        deck.push_back(Card(val,suits[suit]));
}

Card Deck::drawRandomCard()
{
int RandIndex=rand() % deck.size();
Card drawnCard=deck[RandIndex];
deck.erase(deck.begin()+RandIndex);
return drawnCard;

}

void Card::printCard() const { //for debugging purposes
cout << value << " of " << suit << endl;
//want to pass drawnCard here
}
void StudPoker::deal() {
//want to pass drawnCard here
}
```

**header file**

```
class Card{
public:
    int value;
    char suit;
    string drawnCard;
    Card(int value, char suit) : value(value), suit(suit) {}
    void printCard(drawnCard) const;

};
```

Comment: You pass the drawn card as an argument to printcard. If you are not going to change the contents of the card in the printcard method, then just pass a copy of it, not a pointer.

Comment: Passing it as an argument so `printCard(drawnCard)` gives me the error, printCard declared void and drawnCard not declared in this scope. I added it in the class prototype, but in my header I get drawnCard does not name a type error. What type would drawnCard be in this case?

Comment: @aishere You probably need something like `printCard(const Card& drawnCard)` but you're not giving enough context to explain why the errors you got actually appear. Consider to edit your question and give a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Okay, I used what you suggested. Now to simply test my printCard function to see if the output is a random card, what would the call be in main? Since this is a fairly complicated function header, I'm not sure.